# Commit All changes and email the files that were changed/added/deleted

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, popen

I am python and GIT newbie.

My Aim is commit all changes to GIT and email the list of files that were changed/added/deleted. This script will run once a day.

I have come up with this.

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import *

accpath = '/home/Project'
subprocess.Popen(["git","init"],cwd = accpath)

subprocess.Popen(["git","add","."],cwd = accpath)
subprocess.Popen(["git","commit","-a","-m","'committed'"],cwd = accpath)

v = subprocess.Popen(["git","status","-s"],cwd = accpath)
```

output:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/Project/.git/
M  Italy/ACMilan/team.cfg
D Italy/ACMilan/team.tet
A  Italy/ACMilan/team.ttwq
[master 2381802] 'committed'
2 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
delete mode 100644 Italy/ACMilan/team.tet
create mode 100644 Italy/ACMilan/team.ttwq
```

How do I get an understandable output and email it? I only need the M, D, and A parts.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy options for your problem:

Either use Git hooks to push to some API when committing and run some sort of cron script to send the email. http://githooks.com/

Git Hooks run scripts on git events. These scripts can be defined by you. 
A quick run down:

Git hook scripts can be added in any Initialized Git repo.

If you then do `ls -l .git/hooks/` , you will see every hook available to you. If you open up the `pre-commit` hook, You can override the default behaviour. (REMEMBER to backup the original script for when you make a mistake.)

**OR**

Use the github REST API to get commits for the day. That should give you some information https://developer.github.com/v3/ on commits for that day. A sample would be something like the following:

GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits

When calling that you will get a paginated list of commits. (Remember you will need to add authentication headers).

If you only want to receive commits for the day add the since parameter:

GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?since=2018-03-20T00:00:00+02:00

That will give you commits only for the day. Checkout the github REST api docs for the full details.

**For your use case I would recommend using the REST API. Git hooks are better for running unit tests or linters on a pre-commit to prevent bad pull requests**